# Youtube events with chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, youtube

I am having trouble listening to YouTube (video) events with my chrome extension.

I am trying to detect when a youtube video ends and then call a function.

This sample code is the closest I have found to what I want to achieve:
https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/samples#search:pageaction

I have looked at the requestcontentscript docs as well.

Is there a way I can detect a video in the page, then call a function based on it's playback status? (play, pause, end)

Thank you

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9515704/building-a-chrome-extension-inject-code-in-a-page-using-a-content-script

Comment: Hey Xan, thanks for the reply. Although this works for flash players, since it's a chrome extension and chrome forces users to use the HTML5 player in youtube, this probably wouldn't work for me.

Comment: But this is not flash-specific. Please read the answer to the question carefully. This is a canonical answer to a lot of similar questions.

Comment: As stated, by the way, your question is way too broad for Stack Overflow. Please narrow it down and show what you've tried.